# Rails routes testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd

I am new to testing and I have a question.

This code tests if that route is correct, ok?

```
test "root should route to home#index" do
assert_routing "/", {controller: "home", action: "index"}
end
```

How can I test the opposite? I have

```
resources :sessions, :only=>[:new, :create, :destroy]
```

In my routes. How would I test that you can't enter sessions#edit?

Could it be that I should not test that?

EDIT: I forgot to mention it, I'm using the default tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, it will fail unless the test assert_generates raises an "UrlGenerationError" => unable to generate the url for sessions#edit

```
test "route should not exist" do
  begin
    assert_generates "sessions/edit", controller: :sessions, action: :edit
    flunk "Route to should not exist"
  rescue ActionController::UrlGenerationError
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh... that's a nice approach, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RSpec you could do

```
it "does not route to sessions/edit" do
  expect(:get => "/sessions/edit").not_to be_routable
end
```

See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs/be-routable-matcher for more information on writing routing specs

Comment: No, sorry, I forgot to mention it. I'm using the default tools.